# Zero padding slice past end of array in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

In numpy, is there a way to zero pad entries if I'm slicing past the end of the array, such that I get something that is the size of the desired slice?

For example,

```
>>> x = np.ones((3,3,))
>>> x
array([[ 1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.]])
>>> x[1:4, 1:4] # would behave as x[1:3, 1:3] by default
array([[ 1.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.]])
>>> x[-1:2, -1:2]
 array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  1.]])
```

Visually, I'd like the out-of-bounds areas to be zero padded:

[image]

I'm dealing with images and would like to zero pad to signify moving off the image for my application.

My current plan is to use np.pad to make the entire array larger prior to slicing, but indexing seems to be a bit tricky. Is there a potentially easier way?

Comment: I'm afraid manually padding is your only option, as modifying the behavior of `[]` on NumPy arrays is not possible (because `numpy.ndarray` is implemented in C which prohibits dynamically replacing `numpy.ndarray.__getitem__`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I know there is no numpy solution (nor in any package I know) for such a problem. You could do it yourself but it will be a really, really complicated one even if you only want basic slicing. I would suggest you manually [`np.pad`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.pad.html) your array and simply offset your start/stop/step before you actually slice it.

However if all you need to support are integers and slices without step I have some "working code" for this:

```
import numpy as np

class FunArray(np.ndarray):
    def __getitem__(self, item):

        all_in_slices = []
        pad = []
        for dim in range(self.ndim):
            # If the slice has no length then it's a single argument.
            # If it's just an integer then we just return, this is
            # needed for the representation to work properly
            # If it's not then create a list containing None-slices
            # for dim>=1 and continue down the loop
            try:
                len(item)
            except TypeError:
                if isinstance(item, int):
                    return super().__getitem__(item)
                newitem = [slice(None)]*self.ndim
                newitem[0] = item
                item = newitem
            # We're out of items, just append noop slices
            if dim >= len(item):
                all_in_slices.append(slice(0, self.shape[dim]))
                pad.append((0, 0))
            # We're dealing with an integer (no padding even if it's
            # out of bounds)
            if isinstance(item[dim], int):
                all_in_slices.append(slice(item[dim], item[dim]+1))
                pad.append((0, 0))
            # Dealing with a slice, here it get's complicated, we need
            # to correctly deal with None start/stop as well as with
            # out-of-bound values and correct padding
            elif isinstance(item[dim], slice):
                # Placeholders for values
                start, stop = 0, self.shape[dim]
                this_pad = [0, 0]
                if item[dim].start is None:
                    start = 0
                else:
                    if item[dim].start < 0:
                        this_pad[0] = -item[dim].start
                        start = 0
                    else:
                        start = item[dim].start
                if item[dim].stop is None:
                    stop = self.shape[dim]
                else:
                    if item[dim].stop > self.shape[dim]:
                        this_pad[1] = item[dim].stop - self.shape[dim]
                        stop = self.shape[dim]
                    else:
                        stop = item[dim].stop
                all_in_slices.append(slice(start, stop))
                pad.append(tuple(this_pad))

        # Let numpy deal with slicing
        ret = super().__getitem__(tuple(all_in_slices))
        # and padding
        ret = np.pad(ret, tuple(pad), mode='constant', constant_values=0)

        return ret
```

This can be used as follows:

```
>>> x = np.arange(9).reshape(3, 3)
>>> x = x.view(FunArray)
>>> x[0:2]
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5]])
>>> x[-3:2]
array([[0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5]])
>>> x[-3:2, 2]
array([[0],
       [0],
       [0],
       [2],
       [5]])
>>> x[-1:4, -1:4]
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 2, 0],
       [0, 3, 4, 5, 0],
       [0, 6, 7, 8, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

Note that this may be contain Bugs and "not cleanly coded" parts, I've never used this except in trivial cases.

Comment: The code seems complicated. It will make it hard to debug and likely have edge cases error. From tinkering with it quickly I found that it does not work with 3D image.
```>>> x = np.arange(9*3).reshape(3, 3, 3)
>>> x = x.view(FunArray)
>>> x[0:3, 0:3]``` Try this snippet and it will die.

Comment: @off99555 Yeah, it's just covering the "trivial" cases. It needs as many slices as dimensions, e.g: `x[0:3, 0:3, :]` or `f[0:3, 0:3, 0:3]`. It's quite non-trivial to mimic pure NumPy slicing, extending it for any case makes it really convoluted - that's why the code is already quite complicated.

Answer (score 4):

This class can handle your first test (`x[1:4, 1:4]`) and can be modified to handle your other test (i.e. appending zeros to the start) if you so desire.

```
class CustomArray():

    def __init__(self, numpy_array):
        self._array = numpy_array

    def __getitem__(self, val):

        # Get the shape you wish to return
        required_shape = []
        for i in range(2):
            start = val[i].start
            if not start:
                start = 0
            required_shape.append(val[i].stop - start)

        get = self._array[val]

        # Check first dimension
        while get.shape[0] < required_shape[0]:
            get = np.concatenate((get, np.zeros((1, get.shape[1]))))

        # Check second dimension
        get = get.T
        while get.shape[0] < required_shape[1]:
            get = np.concatenate((get, np.zeros((1, get.shape[1]))))
        get = get.T

        return get
```

Here is an example of it's usage:

```
a = CustomArray(np.ones((3, 3)))

print(a[:2, :2])
[[ 1.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.]]

print(a[:4, 1:6])
[[ 1.  1.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 1.  1.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 1.  1.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]]

# The actual numpy array is stored in the _array attribute
actual_numpy_array = a._array
```

Answer (score 3):

### Is there a way? Yes. Is it complicated? Not especially.

```py
import numpy as np
def fill_crop(img, pos, crop):
  '''
  Fills `crop` with values from `img` at `pos`, 
  while accounting for the crop being off the edge of `img`.
  *Note:* negative values in `pos` are interpreted as-is, not as "from the end".
  '''
  img_shape, pos, crop_shape = np.array(img.shape), np.array(pos), np.array(crop.shape),
  end = pos+crop_shape
  # Calculate crop slice positions
  crop_low = np.clip(0 - pos, a_min=0, a_max=crop_shape)
  crop_high = crop_shape - np.clip(end-img_shape, a_min=0, a_max=crop_shape)
  crop_slices = (slice(low, high) for low, high in zip(crop_low, crop_high))
  # Calculate img slice positions
  pos = np.clip(pos, a_min=0, a_max=img_shape)
  end = np.clip(end, a_min=0, a_max=img_shape)
  img_slices = (slice(low, high) for low, high in zip(pos, end))
  crop[tuple(crop_slices)] = img[tuple(img_slices)]
```

#### Why use this?

If memory is a concern, then copying the image into a padded version might not be good. This also works well for higher dimensional inputs, and it's clear how to return indices/slices if you needed those.

#### Why is crop a parameter?

To indicate the padded value, we can instead create the memory for the crop ahead of time with `np.zeros`/`np.full`, then fill in the part that we need. The difficulty then isn't working out where to copy from, but instead, where to paste inside the crop.

#### Theory

Let's look at a 1D case:

[image: Colourful description of 1D case]

If you think about it a little bit, you can see that:

- `crop_low` is as far above `0` as `pos` is below `0`, but if `pos >= 0`, then `crop_low == 0`
- `crop_high` is as far below `crop.shape` as `end` is above `img.shape`, but if `end <= img.shape`, then `crop_high == crop.shape`

If we put this into normal python code, it would look like this:

```py
crop_low = max(-pos, 0)
crop_high = crop.shape - max(end-img.shape, 0)
```

The rest of the code above is just for indexing.

#### Testing

```py
# Examples in 1 dimension
img = np.arange(10, 20)

# Normal
pos = np.array([1,])
crop = np.full([5,], 0)
fill_crop(img, pos, crop)
assert crop.tolist() == [11, 12, 13, 14, 15]

# Off end
pos = np.array([8,])
crop = np.full([5,], 0)
fill_crop(img, pos, crop)
assert crop.tolist() == [18, 19,  0,  0,  0]

# Off start
pos = np.array([-2,])
crop = np.full([5,], 0)
fill_crop(img, pos, crop)
assert crop.tolist() == [ 0,  0, 10, 11, 12]


# Example in 2 dimensions (y,x)
img = np.arange(10, 10+10*10)\
          .reshape([10, 10])
# Off Top right
pos = np.array([-2, 8])
crop = np.full([5, 5], 0)
fill_crop(img, pos, crop)
assert np.all(crop[:2] == 0) # That is, the top two rows are 0s
assert np.all(crop[:, 3:] == 0) # That is, the right 3 rows are 0s
assert np.all(crop[2:, :2] == img[:3, 8:]) 
# That is, the rows 2-5 and columns 0-1 in the crop
#  are the same as the top 3 rows and columns 8 and 9 (the last two columns)
```

And there we have it. The over-engineered answer to the original question.

Comment: Nice solution with efficiency in mind. Though it would be better if you package it into a function or a class with similar interface as a numpy array. That would benefit a lot for me to immediately copy your code without the need to understand anything. lol

Comment: @off99555 I'm unsure what you mean. Is the function I started with insufficient in some way?

Comment: I mean you should make it easy for someone to copy this code and use it. For example, you could create the zero array inside the function and return it instead of asking user to provide it.

Comment: There are 2 reasons I didn't choose that interface. 1. You may not want 0s outside the image area. 2. I motivate this instead of the relatively simpler padding option as a memory efficient solution. This interface allows you to pass views into contiguous blocks of memory, so if you have several crops, you can save creating some memory compared to creating several small `crop`s and then concatenating them later.

Answer (score 1):

For the simplest case of rank 2 or 3 images, here is an example of how to implement zero-padded "slicing" with out-of-bounds indices:

```
def padded_slice(img, sl):
    output_shape = np.asarray(img.shape)
    output_shape[0] = sl[1] - sl[0]
    output_shape[1] = sl[3] - sl[2]
    src = [max(sl[0], 0),
           min(sl[1], img.shape[0]),
           max(sl[2], 0),
           min(sl[3], img.shape[1])]
    dst = [src[0] - sl[0], src[1] - sl[0],
           src[2] - sl[2], src[3] - sl[2]]
    output = np.zeros(output_shape, dtype=img.dtype)
    output[dst[0]:dst[1], dst[2]:dst[3]] = img[src[0]:src[1], src[2]:src[3]]
    return output
```

For example, call this function with `padded_slice(img, [-10, 150, -10, 150])` on a 100x100 image and it will return a 160x160 zero-padded image.

Comment: _...on a 100x100 image and it will return a 160x160 zero-padded image._. Pretty sure OP still wants a 100x100 array in this case, not 160x160

Comment: @smac89 In the original example, they say they want an output that is "the size of the desired slice", not the size of the input. This interpretation also matches the interpretation of other answers.

Answer (score 0):

In case of 1D array I did this, can be useful if someone fall here...

```
def getPaddedSlice(npArray, pos, lenSegment, center = False):
    lenNpArray = len(npArray)
    if center:
        if lenSegment % 2 == 0:
            startIndex = int(pos - math.floor(lenSegment / 2.0)) + 1 
            lastIndex  = int(pos + math.ceil(lenSegment / 2.0))  + 1  

        else : 
            startIndex = int(pos - math.floor(lenSegment / 2.0))
            lastIndex  = int(pos + math.ceil(lenSegment / 2.0)) + 1 
    else:
        startIndex = pos
        lastIndex  = startIndex + lenSegment 

    if startIndex < 0:
        padded_slice = npArray[0: lastIndex]
        padded_slice = np.concatenate((np.zeros(abs(startIndex)), padded_slice))  
    else:
        if center :
            padded_slice = npArray[startIndex: lastIndex]
        else:
            padded_slice = npArray[pos: lastIndex]

    if lastIndex > len(npArray):
        if center :
            padded_slice = npArray[startIndex: pos + lenSegment]
            padded_slice = np.concatenate((padded_slice, np.zeros(lastIndex - len(a))))
        else : 
            padded_slice = npArray[pos: pos + lenSegment]
            padded_slice = np.concatenate((padded_slice, np.zeros(lastIndex - len(a))))

    return padded_slice
```

Usage

```
a = np.asarray([2,2,3,1,7,6,5,4])

for i in range(len(a)):
    b = getPaddedSlice(a, i, lenSegment, True)
    print b
```

Display

```
[0 2 2 3]
[2 2 3 1]
[2 3 1 7]
[3 1 7 6]
[1 7 6 5]
[7 6 5 4]
[6 5 4 0]
[5 4 0 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem has a ton of edge-cases. My solution for a fairly restricted problem-space: Regular slices (i.e. `slice` objects, no masks etc.), `slice.start <= slice.stop and slice.step == 1` per dimension, ideally n-dimensional.

Prerequisites:

```py
from typing import Optional, NamedTuple

import numpy as np
from numpy.typing import ArrayLike

class _Intv(NamedTuple):
    length: int
    buff: slice
    data: slice
```

I want to slice from *data* into a *buffer*. A `buff` array shall be created filled with padding values before data is copied into it from a `data` array. For this, correct indices/slices must be computed first for each array for every dimension. The following helper does this with `data.shape[n] == shape_n`. Note that it only computes intervals and does not yet interact with the data:

```py
def _intervals_1d(intv: slice, shape_n: int) -> _Intv:
    
    assert intv.step in (None, 1)  # works only for steps of length 1
    
    if intv.start is None:
        intv = slice(0, intv.stop)
    if intv.stop is None:
        intv = slice(intv.start, shape_n)
    
    assert intv.start <= intv.stop  # works only if slice's start <= stop
    
    length = intv.stop - intv.start

    if intv.start >= 0:  # no padding at start
        buff_start = 0
        data_start = intv.start
    else:  # padding at start
        buff_start = -intv.start
        data_start = 0
    
    if intv.stop <= shape_n:  # no padding at stop
        buff_stop = length
        data_stop = intv.stop
    else:  # padding at stop
        buff_stop = length - intv.stop + shape_n
        data_stop = shape_n
    
    return _Intv(length, slice(buff_start, buff_stop), slice(data_start, data_stop))
```

It can be applied to the 1D case:

```py
def paddedslice_1d(data: ArrayLike, intv: slice, fill_value: Optional[float] = np.nan) -> ArrayLike:
    
    assert data.ndim == 1
    
    intv = _intervals_1d(intv, data.shape[0])
    buff = np.full((intv.length,), fill_value = fill_value, dtype = data.dtype)
    buff[intv.buff] = data[intv.data]
    
    return buff
```

The following tests are passing:

```py
data_1d = np.array([10, 11, 12, 13])

test = paddedslice_1d(data_1d, intv = slice(None), fill_value = -99)
assert np.all(test == data_1d)

test = paddedslice_1d(data_1d, intv = slice(1, 3), fill_value = -99)
assert np.all(test == np.array([11, 12]))

test = paddedslice_1d(data_1d, intv = slice(-2, 2), fill_value = -99)
assert np.all(test == np.array([-99, -99, 10, 11]))

test = paddedslice_1d(data_1d, intv = slice(2, 6), fill_value = -99)
assert np.all(test == np.array([12, 13, -99, -99]))

test = paddedslice_1d(data_1d, intv = slice(-2, 6), fill_value = -99)
assert np.all(test == np.array([-99, -99, 10, 11, 12, 13, -99, -99]))
```

Based on the initial helper function, the solution can be generalized to n dimensions:

```py
def paddedslice_nd(data: ArrayLike, *intvs: slice, fill_value: Optional[float] = np.nan) -> ArrayLike:
    
    assert data.ndim == len(intvs)
    
    intvs = [_intervals_1d(intv, shape_n) for intv, shape_n in zip(intvs, data.shape)]
    buff = np.full([intv.length for intv in intvs], fill_value = fill_value, dtype = data.dtype)
    buff[tuple(intv.buff for intv in intvs)] = data[tuple(intv.data for intv in intvs)]
    
    return buff
```

The following tests are passing:

```py
data_2d = np.arange(11, 20).reshape(3, 3)

test = paddedslice_nd(data_2d, slice(None), slice(None), fill_value = -99)
assert np.all(test == data_2d)

test = paddedslice_nd(data_2d, slice(-1, None), slice(-1, None), fill_value = -99)
assert np.all(test == np.array([[-99, -99, -99, -99], [-99, 11, 12, 13], [-99, 14, 15, 16], [-99, 17, 18, 19]]))

test = paddedslice_nd(data_2d, slice(-1, 2), slice(-1, 2), fill_value = -99)
assert np.all(test == np.array([[-99, -99, -99], [-99, 11, 12], [-99, 14, 15]]))
```

More complicated edge-cases can be addressed relatively trivially by altering the helper function `_intervals_1d`, which is left as an exercise to the reader ;)